# how to convert xml to csv using nifi

Tags: hadoop, apache-nifi

i have `.xml` file with multiple **row** tags . I want to convert each **row** tag output to **separate** file and put it in `hdfs` using `apache nifi`.

Comment: My suggestion is that you show what you have done so far.

Comment: Please provide the .xml file format and what you have done so far.

Comment: I have tried using XML reader and CSV writer but it is only working for single row tag .any suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the `GetFile`, `SplitXML`, and `PutHDFS` processors. These processors, in that sequence, should provide the functionality you need.

Comment: Andy , can you let me know what split depth I need to provide . If I mention 1 each attribute coming as one record